# How To See At A Glance What Is Shared With Whom in SkyDrive?

Tags: onedrive

Over time, I have shared various things in my Skydrive with various people.  I don't remember what all I've shared over time.  But I can't seem to see a way to easily see what is shared and with whom in Skydrive.

Is there an easy way to identify what is shared without having to click on every individual file and looking at their properties one by one?  (Either in the desktop app or the web app.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know how this can be done through the web application through SkyDrive.com. It is actually quite straightforward.

[image]

- In **red**: the link that is visible on the left menu that allows you to
  see the files shared by you or with you.
- In **blue**: the files shared by
  you.
- In **green**: files shares by someone else with me.

Note: certain SkyDrive features are released to some users first and other users later. However, this particular feature has been around for a while so I don't think you should have a problem being able to do this.